# Pycharm doesn't recognize installed pexpect module

Tags: python, pip, pycharm, pexpect

I tried to install pexpect module using pip. Its been showing up in the installed modules list but when I try to run the script It gives:

> ImportError: No module named pexpect.

**Here is screenshot:**

[image: Here is screenshot]

Comment: try creating a a new file outside of pycharm and see if it works

Comment: I see from the traceback that the ImportError appears when debugging. Does it appear if you simply Run the run configuration, instead of invoking the debugger>